# How would you determine the point at which a object would lose contact with a oscillating bridge, given information?

Tags: gravity, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, equilibrium

I was recently going through question on Simple harmonic motion and came across the example in the photos i could do all the question until the last one which stated to show the time in which the dog would lose contact with the bridge the answer says its at t=0.12 s however at this time the bridge travelling upwards this contradicts my common sense as i thought it would lose contact with the bridge whilst the bridge is a accelerating downwards with a acceleration greater than than of 9.81 so there for the bridge would have to be travelling downwards.For clarification the question i am asking is part e. any guidance to this question would be much appreciated [image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

"i thought it would lose contact with the bridge whilst the bridge is a accelerating downwards with a acceleration greater than than of 9.81"

This is correct.

" so there for the bridge would have to be travelling downwards."

This is incorrect.

As it goes upwards from its mid-position the bridge's upward velocity is getting less and less. So its acceleration is downwards. For example,

At *t* = 0.18 s, *v* = 0.2457 m $\text{s}^{-1}$ up; at *t* = 0.19 s, *v* = 0.1232 m $\text{s}^{-1}$ up,

So between *t* = 0.18 s and *t* = 0.19 s,

$\Delta v$ = 0.1232 m $\text{s}^{-1}$ up – 0.2457 m $\text{s}^{-1}$ up = – 0.1225 m $\text{s}^{-1}$ up = 0.1225 m $\text{s}^{-1}$ down.

So the bridge's mean acceleration between *t* = 0.18 s and *t* = 0.19 s is 12.3 m $\text{s}^{-2}$ down.

Remember, too, that shm may be defined by the equation
$$\text{acceleration} = -\omega^2 \times \text{displacement}.$$

So when the displacement is positive the acceleration is negative.

It's just about possible to reproduce the dog-and-bridge effect by placing a small object on your hand, then raising your hand fast, but bringing it to rest in a very short time. The object will lose contact with your hand!

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is almost correct. The dog will lose contact when the bridge is accelerating downward with magnitude greater than that of $g$. However, velocity and acceleration are independent quantities that need not have the same direction. For the case of a harmonic oscillator, since the velocity is always in the opposite direction of jerk (the derivative of acceleration), the velocity will always be upward the when the acceleration first reaches a certain threshold in the downward direction (unless it started past that threshold).